# Parabola where the $x$ intersect is always $0$ and $1$

Tags: geometry, quadratics

I am working on creating a parabola where the $x$ intersect is always $0$ and $1$ for basic needs the one below works great!

$$
y=-d\cdot a^{2}\left(x\ -.5\right)^{a}\ +d
$$

but I am attempting to change the angle which, I am not even sure if that is the correct term, but it is my $a$ above, only $2$ and $4$ seem to actually work with this equation, I kind of understand why, but I cannot determine what I need to change for allow any even value for $a$.

I am very bad at math (compared to pretty much everyone on here) and I really get by on testing and doing and seeing how it affects the curve. I would like to have it as simple as possible and getting "close" is good enough, for me, I just need it between 0 and 1 for a percentage.

**edit** Based upon the suggestions, I realized I forgot an aspect to the question, the d variable is required as I want it set from $0$ to $1$ to where if $d$ is $1$ and $x$ is $.5$ then $y$ is $1$.

My goal is to find the distance from 0 (y) based upon the location (x) where (d) is the max distance to travel.

Example of what I want: https://desmos.com/calculator/vld0cp7zs0 and how a when anything other than 2 or 4 breaks the x intercept requirement.

**edit 2** after working with this a bit more I ended up with:
$$
y=-d\cdot2^{a\cdot.4}\left(x\ -.5\right)^{a\cdot.4}\ +d
$$

which is simplified to:

$$
y=d\left(1-(2x-1)^{0.4a}\right)
$$

a now has to be a whole number and it gets me pretty much exactly what I want.
Here is a link to both of my new equations.
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/jicyg0sa7h

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps try this:
$$
y = a  x(x-1)
$$
where $a$ can vary however you like. Every parabola passing through $0$ and $1$ on the $x$-axis has this form, so it's a complete solution to your problem.

If you'd like a little more adjustability, you could try

$$
y = a  x^k(x-1)^k
$$
where $k = 2, 4, 6, $ should give you parabolic-like things with pointier or flatter bottoms.

Comment: This is close, but it is missing one critical piece to my requirements (which I totally forgot to explain) so I edited the original question to cover that.

Comment: Why do you mention those three values for $k$? As far as I can see any value will work. It would be prudent to mention the correlation between various values and the "pointyness" of the resulting curve (which is *not* a hyperbola for $k\neq 1$).

Comment: Right, so the issue I have is I also need to define a set distance from 0 on the y axis, so if you take my equation and put it in here:
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/vld0cp7zs0

When I start tweaking the $a$ it breaks it, I tried it with your equation as well while you are correct, my goal is to also control the shape of the curve. You can see when you change a it does change the shape, but it also does not always pass through 0 and 1 unless it is 2 or 4. But with your equation, I cannot modify the shape, it is always "2" essentially.

Comment: Well, you did say "a parabola", which unfortunately has a very specific meaning. I tried to generalize in my second equation (with the $k$), but ...

Comment: Sorry!!! I didn't mean to lead you down the wrong path with incorrect terminology!

Comment: I am marking this one as correct as it got me thinking about how to do it! Even though no one could decipher what I wanted (admittedly my own fault) I think this one helped out the most. I appended the answer I cam up with to the question.

Answer (score 0):

For a parabola to always intersect with the $x$ axis at $0$ and $1$, it must have the factors $(x-0)$ and $(x-1)$. The product of these already gives you a parabola, and all possible parabolas satisfying your condition are:
$$y = A(x-0)(x-1)=Ax(x-1)$$
where $A\neq 0$ is any scalar (real number).

Comment: Hmm there is one more requirement I didn't think of when posting, in my original post, d is the "distance" from 0 to 1 on the y axis, so I need the ability to define a distance that the curve travels as well, so for me if the distance is 1 (100%) It would be the mid point .5 for x. I edited it to be more clear maybe...

Comment: I feel like I don't understand your requirement. Can you please state it precisely?

Comment: $x=0.5$ is the minimum\maximum of the parabola. Do you want it to have a $y$ value of $1$? Meaning, do you want $y(0.5)=1$?

Comment: Sorry, I am terrible at explaining math, I kinda muddled my way through it. If you were to take my original equation and set $a$ to 2 or 4 and $d$ from 0 to 1, it is exactly what I want, but if you start changing $a$ to lets say 6, it no longer passes through 0 and 1 on the $x$ intersect, that is my issue really.

Comment: If you want a graph of the form $y = \dots$ and you want it to pass through $x=0$ and $x=1$, then you want something of the form $y = \text{(stuff)} x^p (x-1)^q$

Answer (score 0):

The general form of a parabola with roots at $0$ and $1$ is $y = a x (x-1)$.

Because parabolas are symmetrical, the maximum height it will obtain will be in the middle of two roots (so in this case the maximum $y$ value will be obtained when $x = \frac{1}{2}$).

So $y_\max = a \frac{1}{2} (\frac{1}{2} - 1) = -\frac{1}{4}a$.

In other words $a = -4 y_\max = -4d$, where I'm defining $d = y_\max$.

---

Putting $y = ax(x-1)$ and $a = -4d$ together gives us:

$$y = -4dx(x-1)$$

Comment: So this is exactly correct, if I wanted the shape of the curve to be constant, but if you look at my example here: https://desmos.com/calculator/vld0cp7zs0 

You can see that when I modify "a" it changes the flatness of the top, but if a is 6 and d is between 0 and 1, it breaks it. That is my main issue.

d = my desired distance on the y axis
a = my "angle" which modifies the shape of the curve

a is breaking my 0 and 1 requirement on the x intercept.